# How do I modify a Yaesu FT-726R from Japan with limited VHF 2 meter bands to use US VHF 2 meter bands?

Tags: yaesu, 2m-band, modification

I purchased this online an love the radio but VHF is limited to 144.00 to 146.00. Our local repeater is at 146.760. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are also so-called mods for the ham radios, and some sites have a collection of them. Out of respect for their work, I won't just copy the instructions, but you can find this one with coverage extension under the name "Expansion mod for the Yaesu FT-726". Mods.dk is such a place, and so is this one: http://www.fracassi.net/iw2ntf/manuali/All%20Yaesu%20Mods.pdf